# how to add parent filter in Magento2 product collection?

Tags: magento2, product, product-collection

How to load new product collection in Magento 2 something like

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', null);
```

I want all simple product which is not  associate with configurable which mean it has no parent.

Or any other approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added following join to the product collection query

```
 $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        'catalog_product_super_link',
        'e.entity_id = catalog_product_super_link.product_id'
    )->where ("catalog_product_super_link.product_id IS NULL");
```

and got the desired collection.